# undefined method 'each_pair' with openstruct

Tags: ruby, string, hash, openstruct

I'm using OpenStruct to manipulate a json like this: `OpenStruct.new '{"age":100,"name":"name"}'` and I'm getting

`` NoMethodError:
       undefined method `each_pair' for "{\"age\":100,\"name\":\"name\"":String ``

this piece of code was working some time ago, and now it's not.

I'm using Ruby 2.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do as :

```
require 'json'

OpenStruct.new(JSON.parse(your_string))
```

[`JSON.parse`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse) will convert your json string object to Ruby Hash object.

Comment: ... and maybe you don't need `OpenStruct` then

Comment: @roman.brodetski same here, as I don't know what OP's actual intention is, so didn't comment on the same.

Comment: I'm using openstruct so that I don't need to `json['key']`, I can `struct.key`